# How To Get Temp Table to Run Multiple Time

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I'm using MS SQL Server.  I'm currently working on a query for pulling headcount.  In this process, I'm creating temp tables, but noticed that I can only run the query once.  If I try running it again after making changes, it gives me the 'There is already an object named '#Test1' in the database.'

My SQL looks like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF    
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Headcount') IS NOT NULL  
Drop Table #Test1
Select Coalesce(Enddate,GETDATE()) as EndDate1,FirstName,LastName,EmployeeID,CostCenter,JobCode, CompanyCode
Into #Test1
from EmployeeDM.dbo.vEmployeeJobReporting EJ
--Group By FirstName,LastName,EmployeeID,CostCenter
Order by 1

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Headcount') IS NOT NULL
Drop Table #Final1
Select max(EndDate1) as Date1, FirstName,LastName,EmployeeID,CostCenter,JobCode, CompanyCode
Into #Final1
From #Test1
Group by FirstName,LastName,EmployeeID,CostCenter,JobCode, CompanyCode
Order by 1

SELECT F.CostCenter,F.FirstName,F.LastName, F.Date1, F.CompanyCode, F.JobCode,F.EmployeeID,(t3.Day_of_Month-t2.Day_of_Month+1)*1.0/t4.Day_of_Month as Headcount,

       Case
```

The last Select statement is the start of the non-temp table query.  What can I do / write in the code to be able to run multiple times in a row?  Also, the error I'm receiving:

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 4
There is already an object named '#Test1' in the database.

Thanks!

Comment: Well...Your very first check is dropping #Test1 but only if #Headcount exists. perhaps that is the problem?? You do the same thing again for #Final1.

Comment: And just a suggestion...you really should order by column names instead of ordinal positions. If you change your query you might get incorrect data because the order by is wrong.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion!  Yes, it was part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write ...INTO #test1, you are creating the table based on the content of the select statement.  You need to either 1) drop the temp tables at the end of your query, 2) check for them existing at the front end and drop if they exist, 3) both.

You are already checking for #headcount, but dropping #final and #test1 at the beginning.  I dont see where you are declaring #headcount as a table?

Comment: That was basically the issue.  Still new to SQL.  Thanks for the help!